# select dynamics generated from an input - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

What I need is that it works as in the example that I send you but when the add buttons appear that when clicking it generates the other dynamic select and not that the select is generated automatically, the only select that is generated automatically is the first one where it is not the add button appears.

https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-babbage-e8fb2?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I dont understand the problem.  Can you be more specific and can you also please post the code in the question.  I know the code is in the code sandbox, but clarity should also be in the question.

Comment: Hello, I mean, what I need is that in the buttons that say add, I generate the dynamic select, since as well as the select, when selecting a value, it generates another select and the idea is that the buttons that are called add generate it